# How reuse cells works in UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView with several different type of rows. I use 2 prototype cells because all of my cells can be covered by those 2 prototypes. Inside each prototype I have 2 labels - upper and lower.

I dynamically fill content of those cell dependently of the section and row to which they belong. But I have issue with reuse.

I set dynamic image inside one of the cells (according specific conditions). My problem is that when I scroll - the image appears on the next page inside the cell which should not have such image. I suppose this is the result of reuse.

I try to remove that image if the cell is of that (second type). This works fine on iPhone, because the data is on different screens (when I scroll to the second cell the first is outside of the screen). My problem is that this not works on iPad - because both cells are on the same page.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Clear your cells in the `prepareForReuse` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me explain how Reuseidentifier works.
Lets say if you have three cells that are visible on view .

You scroll you tableveiw first cell that was on display is scrolled up is not visible now will be deque and your fourth cell will use that cell.

This is just in short I can explain it but there is lot more details available.

Whats happening in your case is your one cell can be easily reused for the other as you scroll.
You have to place switch or if else properly to handle it.
If you explain your case better and add code cellforrow then can help you better.
I hope this will help you to fix your problem.

Comment: 10x, @Imran. You give me a clue. Before configuring the cell (`configureCell`) I clear this icon (inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).